# Automatically set owner to new files in a NFS Folder

Tags: linux, nfs, file-permissions

I have a machine which acts as a NFS server, this machine shares files with others.
Developers use the *dev-user* to upload files to the NFS server, but in the NFS client those files need to be owned by *web-user*, and devs don't have the credentials to log into the web servers everytime and do chown to those files.
**I want that everytime files are uploaded to the NFS client they are owned automatically by web-user**.

I have tried with ACL with no result.
And Nfsv4_ACL is confuse.

Is this possible? or do i have to seek other options?

Comment: does this help: https://serverfault.com/a/841210/127530

Answer (score 0):

Several hacks and work-arounds are possible. In no particular order:

- synchronise the UID numbers used for the `dev-user` and `web-user` accounts.
  That may have impact elsewhere so that will take careful planning.
- rather than using NFS use SMB to export and mount the file share.
  The CIFS (SMB) mount option supports the  `uid=arg`, `gid=arg` and `forceuid` arguments to set the uid/gid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem from the client.  The ID's may be specified as either a name or a numeric uid/gid.
- NFSv4 allows for ID mapping and translation. See for example [`man idmand.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/idmapd.conf) and [Mapping UID and GID of local user to the mounted NFS share](https://serverfault.com/q/514118/794142)
  That should allow you to for example use on your web-servers:

  ```
  # /etc/idmapd.conf
  ...
  [Static]

  dev-user@NFS-SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM = web-user
  ```

Comment: The static mapping works only for kerberized access